# share images in website in facebook with jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

i have in my website image gallery i want every user click on share button and share any picture in facebook my code is here

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=hi&p[url]=http://example.com&p[summary]=bye&p[images][0]=http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rm.jpg"
```

but description and image and title not show in facebook share dialog ! only show my website information in share window!

Answer (score 0):

sharer.php does not allow any additional parameters anymore, see here: [How do I customize Facebook's sharer.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547088/how-do-i-customize-facebooks-sharer-php)

Other share possibilities: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed

Open Graph Tags you need for the sharer.php to work: http://ogp.me/